# Updating a non-primitive value in an oData v4 entity with openUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've got an entity which contains some primitive values (strings and dates) and a navigation property (user). I built a formular to edit said entity and select a user from a dropdown list. I'm struggeling with setting the selected user to the root entity. As mentioned in API the method [sap.ui.model.odata.v4.Context#methods/setProperty](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.Context#methods/setProperty) can only update primitive values. I could build a workaround using actions for setting the relationship to the selected user in a custom request, but it don't feels like best practice.

Can anybody help me with this? How can I set/update a navigation propterty of an existing entity?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the user connected to the parent entity? Imo it makes more sense to update the child with the key of the parent.

Comment: It is connected as an oData Navigation Property. And it's an 1:n relation.So each user can be linked in multiple formulars. (this is also a very simplified scenario of my real workcase)

Comment: Of course it has a navigation property, but surely there is some kind of foreign key relationship on a database level?

Comment: on database side there would be a foreign key for the user in the formular-entity. But I don't see how that matters in that case, because the odata service fully encapsulate the database-level. I'm struggeling with the best practice at client side. I'm gonna add some code to showcase my situation

Comment: in scenarios like this, the "usual practise" is to set the foreign key field, not the object link. In OData API you can retarget the link but in SAP its just as effective and far simpler to juts set the key field and the let the framework  do the rest. After all it is only the key field that changes in the database anyway